# App to watch 360-degree VR YouTube videos in cardboard on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone-app, itunes

There is official cardboard app for iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/google-cardboard/id987962261

> Cardboard puts virtual reality on your iPhone. The Google Cardboard app helps you set up a Cardboard viewer and includes a few experiences to get you started

*(but doesn't allow to watch existing YouTube videos)*

There is support page for 360 degrees videos: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6239930

> With Cardboard and the **YouTube Android app**, you can even watch 360 degree videos for an immersive experience

*(emphasis mine - feature is supported in Android - not iOS)*

---

**EDIT: I did some more research**

1. http://www.wareable.com/vr/best-vr-apps-iphone-android-mobile

> Then type #360video into YouTube, look for the VR icon and strap on a viewer to see 2D online vids via your headset.

*(confirming with the author)*

2. https://old.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/3ba1io/was_cardboard_support_for_youtube_on_ios_disabled/cskjpsz
   https://old.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/3ba1io/was_cardboard_support_for_youtube_on_ios_disabled/

---

Is there an app *(either paid or free)* that allows to display video in cardboard format on iOS devices?

Comment: FYI, the New York Times recently released the free app [NYT VR](https://appsto.re/us/H2Pt9.i) for their own content. Works with Google Cardboard. NYT even gave a Google Cardboard to their subscribers. Also, the [Puppy Bowl 2016](http://www.animalplanet.com/tv-shows/puppy-bowl/games-and-more/puppy-bowl-virtual-reality/) will be shown in VR.

Comment: :) FYI... At #websummit conference there was a dedicated area for the startups operating in VR industry, cost of Cardboard dropped from $20 to $2 and according to some numbers form Google I/O 2015 they sold over million - now as I was searching for reference for this claim - http://thenextdigit.com/27985/google-cardboard-5-million-sold/ - ```As of Jan. 27, 2016, Google has shipped 5 million Cardboard viewers.``` - if you add all the cheap copies available on eBay... *(that would be a big number)* **My point? Hello world, VR is no longer geeky, it's in the mainstream"**

Answer (score 1):

I hope iOS version of YouTube will catchup soon.

**UPDATE: Fri 27 May:** I've just noticed that YouTube app for iOS supports now cardboard view.

---

I know there is a curated list of phone viewers here: http://www.vrfavs.com/#Phone_VR_viewers

I managed to find a workflow that works for me but it's slightly complicated, time consuming, doesn't scale and is not easily distributable. And yet, this is my best bet as of now...

*(hoping to receive updated answers soon)*

1. Get the .mp4 version of the video
2. Copy to iPhone via iTunes *(even though it is a video it has to be copies to photos, not videos)*
3. Open via Homido Player
4. Wait for conversion to finish
5. Profit!

Waiting for conversion is painful, I'd rather store the final video and be able to play it without waiting.